# Aligning <span> to bottom of List Item using Flexbox

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I have a horizontal list for navigation items, and each navigation item can have a "small text" area and a "large" text area, using `<span>` tags.  So for example, the end result should look like this:

[image]

Notice the last navigation item has no "small text" section, and it aligns with the bottom areas of the navigation.  Currently, my code looks like this:

**navigation.scss**

```
.nav {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5em;

    ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        margin-top: auto;

        li {
            cursor: pointer;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 65px;
            list-style: none;
            margin: .25em;
            margin-bottom: auto;
            padding: .65em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
            position: relative;
            text-align: left;
            white-space: nowrap;

            span:first-child {
                font-size: .75em;
                font-weight: 500;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            span:nth-child(2) {
                font-size: 1.15em;
                font-weight: 600;
                margin-top: auto;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**navigation.html**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Nav Item</span>
            <span>NUMBER ONE</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Nav Item</span>
            <span>NUMBER TWO</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <span></span>
            <span>NUMBER THREE</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this code, the last navigation item "NUMBER THREE" does not align with the bottom text in the other two navigation items.  It aligns it either with the middle or the top of the `<li>` item.  I tried using aligning via `flex-end` and that did not do the trick.  The end goal is to align the second `<span>` tag to the bottom so it aligns with the other navigation items.  Does anyone have any ideas of how to align  I am using flexbox with SASS (SCSS) in an Angular app.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need your `li` to be a flexbox. Both `span` should be `display:block`, with a specified height. If you do not specify an element's height, and it has no content, it will collapse. If you provide a JSFiddle or similar, I can show an example.

Comment: The code you posted already achieves your goal: https://jsfiddle.net/2nesq1td/1/ (I only compiled the CSS.)

Comment: @Michael_B, you are correct, the JSFiddle shows it works as I expect, but my angular implementation of it is still not looking correct.  It's so weird.  Nevertheless, I know I am on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a `display: block` and a `margin-top: auto` to the second child `span` selector:

```
span:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

That did the trick.